# How to get Project Site connected with project in Project Server 2013?

Tags: development, project-server

How I can get the Project Site connected with particular project in Project Server?

Because I want to get all SPLisItems from Risks List related with concrete project site of project server.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have access to the reporting database, the URL is in a field named "ProjectWorkspaceInternalHRef" in the Project table. The same field is also available via REST.

Though, basic information about Risks are already in the reporting database in a table named MSP_WSSRisk, so you don't need to do extra work for those. (If any custom columns were added, you'd need to do what you're doing, but for OOB fields, there is already a job that will populate the table in the reporting db automatically.)